# Colored Text From Html Is Just White

Tags: java, kotlin

I am trying to color some text and then setting the text property of the control using `Html.fromHtml()` but it's just returning white and I am not sure why.

```
buyPrice.setText("BUY: " + Html.fromHtml(getColoredSpanned(recommendeditem.getItemLowPrice(), "#ff3c3c")));

private String getColoredSpanned(String text, String color) {
    String input = "<font color=" + color + ">" + text + "</font>";
    return input;
}
```

getItemLowPrice

```
public String getItemLowPrice() {
    return String.format(NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US).format(Long.parseLong(mLowPrice)));
}
```

This happens when I click a button there is nothing else but the button click and that

Comment: Font is not an HTML Tag, maybe you meant span?

Comment: @JosefKorbel `<font>` is an HTML tag. I'm not sure the object the OP uses supports it, but it is indeed an HTML tag.

Comment: You're right, it is an archaic tag, but not supported by HTML5

Answer (score 0):

try to use this method because html.fromhtml method is deprecated

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static Spanned fromHtml(String html){
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
   return Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
} else {
   return Html.fromHtml(html);
}
}

public static final int FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT = 63;
public static final int FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY = 0;
public static final int FROM_HTML_OPTION_USE_CSS_COLORS = 256;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_BLOCKQUOTE = 32;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_DIV = 16;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_HEADING = 2;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_LIST = 8;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_LIST_ITEM = 4;
public static final int FROM_HTML_SEPARATOR_LINE_BREAK_PARAGRAPH = 1;
public static final int TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_CONSECUTIVE = 0;
public static final int TO_HTML_PARAGRAPH_LINES_INDIVIDUAL = 1;
```

try to read about the different flags on the Html class documentation
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html#FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT